# JavaScript call a click handling function on page load without passing event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a function that expects click event object as parameter.
For example:

```
toggle: function (e) {
//does all the required work and then calls cancelEvent

this.cancelEvent(e);//IMPORTANT TO HANDLE LOCAL ANCHORS
    },


cancelEvent:function(e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
        if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
                  } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
                  }
    },
```

I need to call toggle function on the page load.

I tried calling it without passing event parameter. However, doing so breaks the expected functionality and everything becomes un-editable.

Is there anyway I can get the current event object and pass it to the function?

Or should I attach load event too the event listener?

Please let me know what is the way out?

Answer (score 1):

No need to even use jQuery. JavaScript in the browser includes a native Event object. So you should be able to call your toggle function directly (assuming you have access to the scope it was defined in) like this...

```
var fakeEvent = new Event('click');
toggle(fakeEvent);
```

Be sure to test thoroughly. If your code is relying on certain property values that the event would only have if it were triggered from a real user click then this may not work for you.

A better option would be to refactor so that the functionality that is shared by both page load and click is factored into a new function which can be called from both the click event handler function and the page load logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create an event using jQuery:

```
var e = $.Event('click');
$element.trigger(e); // Triggers click event on element
```

[Here's documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event) on `$.Event`. Triggering a click event using jQuery the following way would also create an event object for you:

```
$element.click();
```